# Hiding the Scheduled Toast Notification when app is running in windows store

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am using Schedule toast notification in windows store app (C#/XAML). The toast is showed on the correct time, but i didnot find any event fired in the app simillar to OnPushNotificaiton, (which fires when push notification is received, i.e even before the toast is displayed.). my requirement is simple that i don't want to show toast when the app is running state instead want to show some flyout to display the message from toast

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple choices what you can do is when your application launches get a list of the notifications that are still pending for your app from the NotificationManager and set the SuppressPopup option to true. When you close the application you can reset it to false.

You can see more documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.scheduledtoastnotification.aspx

I hope this helps